# Is some way to can call recyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(view) in the UltimateRecyclerView library?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using the library UltimateRecyclerView

In Recyclerview I can do this call with RecyclerView:

mRecyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(view)

But in the library this method it doesn't exist.

How can I do the same using the library??

Some help will be apreciate!

Comment: maybe you should just ask the owner of the github project.

Comment: I found the solution, passing the position instead of .getChildLayoutPosition(view)